# GPU Accelerated Harris Corner Detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, glsl, feature-detection

I am trying to use GLSL to implement a Harris Corner Detection. But it does not work properly(I am guessing). First off it doesn't detect all corners and it detects alot of points that are not corners, another big problem is that it the threshold is very specific for each image. Maybe that is normal with a Harris detector?

All help is appreciated.

Shader Passes:

1st: Standard passthrough.

2nd: I turn the image into a grayscale image.

3rd: Sobel filtering the image and passing the x, y  gradient intensitys and the product of the xy intensitys.

```
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    varying vec2 vUV;

    void main() {

        vec2 uv = vUV;
        // Offset used to get access to neighbours
        float w = 1.0/800.0;
        float h = 1.0/600.0;

        vec3 temp;
        vec3 sum = vec3(0.0);
        // Sobel - Edge Detection
        // y gradient
        vec3 texel0 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-w, h)).xyz;
        vec3 texel1 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-w, 0)).xyz;
        vec3 texel2 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-w, -h)).xyz;

        vec3 texel6 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(w, h)).xyz;
        vec3 texel7 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(w, 0)).xyz;
        vec3 texel8 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(w, -h)).xyz;

        vec3 vertEdge = 1.0 * texel0 + (2.0*texel1) + 1.0 * texel2 -
                        (1.0 * texel6 + (2.0*texel7) + 1.0 * texel8);
        // x gradient
        vec3 texe0 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-w,h)).xyz;
        vec3 texe1 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0, h)).xyz;
        vec3 texe2 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(w, h)).xyz;

        vec3 texe6 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(-w,-h)).xyz;
        vec3 texe7 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(0,-h)).xyz;
        vec3 texe8 = texture2D(texture, uv + vec2(w,-h)).xyz;

        vec3 horizEdge = 1.0 * texe0 + (2.0*texe1) + 1.0 * texe2 -
                        (1.0 * texe6 + (2.0*texe7) + 1.0 * texe8);

        // Gradient intensity values
        float iy = (vertEdge.r + vertEdge.g + vertEdge.b) /3.0;
        float ix = (horizEdge.r + horizEdge.g + horizEdge.b)  /3.0;
        // Absolute to get negative values
        iy = abs(iy);
        ix = abs(ix);
        float gradProcduct = ix * iy;


        gl_FragColor = vec4(ix,iy,gradProcduct, 0.0);
```

**Not the best looking code - just want it to work for now**

4th and 5th: Standard Gaussian Blur

6th: Calculating Harris Response.
If it is a corner i paint that pixel in magenta.

```
        void main() {

        vec2 uv = vUV;
        float w = 1.0/800.0;
        float h = 1.0/600.0;

        float threshold = 0.05;

        vec4 gradientInfo = texture2D(texture, uv);

        /**************    Harris Reponse   **********************
         R is calculated as R = det(M)- K(Trace(M)) which leads to
         R = Ix^2*Ix^y - Ixy^2-K(ix^2+iy^2)^2
         Ix = X-gradient intesity 
         Iy = Y-gradient intesity 
         Ixy = product of the X- and Y-gradient intensities
         *********************************************************/
        float R =       pow(gradientInfo.r,2.0)*pow(gradientInfo.g,2.0)
                    -   pow(gradientInfo.b,2.0)
                    -   threshold * pow((pow(gradientInfo.r,2.0)+pow(gradientInfo.g,2.0)),2.0);
        vec4 test;
        //if(R > 0.000000000005)
        if(R > 0.0000000000750){
                // Extremely small values, ugly solution for now to be able to use R in maxSuppress
             test  = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, R*1000000000.0);
        }
        else
            test = vec4(vec3(gradientInfo.xyz),0.0);


        gl_FragColor = vec4( test);
    }
```

Result on a simple square:

[image]

Result on a more complex figure with the same R and threshold:

[image]

And the result when the response check is multiplied by a 1000. Doesn't really seem to work.

[image]

Below is the code for the maximum suppression:

```
void main() {

        vec2 uv = vUV;
        float vOffset = 1.0/800.0;
        float hOffset = 1.0/600.0;
        vec4 neighbourPixels[9];

        vec3 result;
        int check = 0;
        vec3 previous = texture2D(texture2, uv).xyz;
        vec4 current = texture2D(texture, uv);
        float temp = current.a;
        vec4 neighbourArray[25];

        if(current.a > 0.0){

            for(int i = -2; i<3;i++){
                for(int j = -2; j<3;j++){
                    if(temp < texture2D(texture, vUV.xy+vec2(i,j)*vec2(vOffset,hOffset)).a ){
                            //result = vec3(1.0,0.0,1.0);
                            check = 1;
                            break;
                    }    
                }
                if(check==1){
                    break;
                }       
            }   
            if(check==1){
                result = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
            }
            else{
                result = vec3(0.0,1.0,1.0);  
            }

        }
        else{
            result = previous.xyz;
        }

        gl_FragColor = vec4( result, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for local maxima in the Harris response, rather than just thresholding. Dilate the response with a 3x3 or 5x5 box, then find pixels whether original response and dilated version are equal.

Comment: I do that in the next step. But that does not eliminate the "false corners".

Answer (score 0):

Harris uses the structure tensor. For the structure tensor you must blur the square of the x derivative (not square the blurred derivative), and likewise for the y derivative. The two diagonal elements are the blurred of the product of the x and y derivatives (you compute the product of the magnitudes of the blurred derivatives).

So:

1. Square the derivatives before computing the blur.
2. Remove the `abs()` calls before computing the product.

Both of these can be done by

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(ix*ix, iy*iy, ix*iy, 0.0);
```

Those three image planes must then be blurred, and the subsequent computation updated to reflect we already have squares.